# CodeIgniter active record used by 2 actions

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a case in my project to execute 2 queries with same condition and clause in mysql.
To the point, this is the sample code :

**Model**

```
public function action_1(){
   $this->db->where('id', 2);
   return $this->db->update('tbl_1', array('name'=>'aldi'));
}
public function action_2(){
   $this->db->where('id', 2);
   return $this->db->delete('tbl_2');
}
```

**Controller**

```
$this->model->action_1();
$this->model->action_2();
```

I think this is less efficient. And my question is, can I just write in model something like :

```
public function do_all_actions(){
   $this->db->where('id', 2);

   $this->db->update('tbl_1', array('name'=>'aldi'));
   $this->db->delete('tbl_2');
}
```

And :

```
$this->model->do_all_actions()
```

In Controller?? Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
public function do_all_actions(){
   $this->db->where('id', 2);
    $this->db->update('tbl_1', array('name'=>'aldi'));

    $this->db->where('id', 2);
    $this->db->delete('tbl_2');
```

}